# How do i get the coordinates of vertices of shapes instead of the control corners coordinates in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

The following code gives me the coordinates of control corners but I want to calculate the coordinates of vertices of a triangle, pentagon, hexagon, etc.

```js
<!-- fabric js function to return coordinates-->
function getCoords(oCoords) {
  return {
    tl: new fabric.Point(oCoords.tl.x, oCoords.tl.y),
    tr: new fabric.Point(oCoords.tr.x, oCoords.tr.y),
    bl: new fabric.Point(oCoords.bl.x, oCoords.bl.y),
    br: new fabric.Point(oCoords.br.x, oCoords.br.y)
  }
}

<!--fabric js event handler-->
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e){
  console.log('over1',e.target)
  if(e.target && e.target !== canvas.getActiveObject())
    canvas.setActiveObject(e.target)
  var thisCoords = getCoords(canvas.getActiveObject().oCoords);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i get middle corner's coordinates of a shape in fabric js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474687/how-do-i-get-middle-corners-coordinates-of-a-shape-in-fabric-js)

Comment: Are all your polygons regular? If yes, then there is a simple trigonometric algorithm to fetch each of the polygon's vertices.

Comment: I got the solution, Objects points array itself is the coordinates of verices of shapes

Comment: Initially , I will draw the regular polygons and then when I stretch the shape using control corners obviously it becomes irregular polygon and I am saving these irregular polygon points array so that next time I draw the shape with those saved points ,I  will be getting the same stretched shape.